# Heroku scheduler with Sidekiq and redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I have an app on Rails 3.2 which is deployed on `Heroku` with `unicorn`. It requires a job to be executed every hour. So I have added `Heroku Scheduler` Addon which heroku provides.

I have also integrated `Sidekiq` and `Redis` with my app.

Following are the code snippet:

config/initializer/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] }
end unless ENV['OPENREDIS_URL'].blank?
```

config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
  end

  Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] }
  end unless ENV['OPENREDIS_URL'].blank?

  Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
end
```

The issue is: Whenever the rake task that I mentioned in Heroku Scheduler is executed, it gives following error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

Trying to figure out what is wrong here?

UPDATE:
On a side note, it is happening only for Heroku scheduler tasks. Other background jobs are working fine.

Comment: why not use Sidekiqs ability to schedule jobs and keep it all in sidekiq without the need to use the scheduler?

Comment: I think Heroku doesn't allow to schedule jobs. We have to use Heroku Scheduler for scheduling jobs.

Comment: you can schedule jobs inside sidekiq for future execution - works fine on Heroku.

Comment: is it a recurring job? Means running every 5 minutes, or so.

Comment: yep, once it completes it just reschedules itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, got it working by adding Sidekiq client configuration to `sidekiq.rb`.

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] }
end unless ENV['OPENREDIS_URL'].blank?

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["OPENREDIS_URL"] }
end unless ENV['OPENREDIS_URL'].blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to leave the URL empty and set the REDIS_PROVIDER environment variable to OPENREDIS_URL.